# EasyAdmin: Display integer cent-amount as Euro/Dollar (like MoneyType with `divisor`) in list view

Tags: php, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

When storing a currency value as integer (i.e. Cent), is there a way to display it in *list view* as Euro/Dollar?

Example: € 900 are stored in the database as `90000`. EasyAdmin displays this as `90,000`. What I'd like to have is `900` (or `900,00` or `900.00`).

In EasyAdmin's *form view*, you can configure this via:

```
form:
    fields:
        - { property: 'centAmount', type: 'money', type_options: { divisor: 100, currency: 'EUR' } }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with the MoneyField (Easy Admin 3).

This is how I fixed it:

```
MoneyField::new('price','Prix')
    ->setCurrency('EUR')
    ->setCustomOption('storedAsCents', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

`MoneyType` is not supported in list view, see https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/1995

Here's the workaround outlined at https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/1995#issuecomment-356717049 :

1. Create a file `/templates/easy_admin/money.html.twig` with:

   ```
   {% if value is null %}
       {{ include(entity_config.templates.label_null) }} {# otherwise `null` will be displayed as `0,00 €` #}
   {% else %}
       {{ (value/100)|number_format(2, ',', '.') }} € {# you can omit the `number_format()` filter if you don’t want the cents to be shown #}
   {% endif %}
   ```

   See `/vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Resources/views/default/field_integer.html.twig` for the template that EasyAdmin uses by default.
2. Activate your new template in `easy_admin.yaml`:

   ```
   list:
       fields:
           - {property: 'centAmount', template: 'easy_admin/money.html.twig' }
   ```

Result: `900,00 €`

Reference: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/list-search-show-configuration.html#rendering-entity-properties-with-custom-templates

Comment: You can also use type_options values:

`{{ (value/field_options.type_options.divisor)|number_format(2, ',', '.') }} {{ field_options.type_options.currency }}`